# Samsung SSD in older Imac (24" Alu)? Trim support?

Tags: macos, imac, ssd, trim

I have an older 24" iMac (Model 8.1 with Mountain Lion) and would like to extend its life a bit by adding a 256GB SSD.  Samsung SSDs seem to be coming down in price (and are possibly well reusable if the iMac retires at some point) and I've looked at the tear-down of the model which appears to be doable (no glued parts).

Does anyone have experience with putting 3rd party SSDs in an older machine?  And if so, will it support SDD TRIM?

Comment: As of 2015 (technology is moving on) you can get several brands of SSD for older Macs that are compatible (even with OS 10.5 / 6) and dont need additional Trim activation such as those by OWC which have built in maintenance. This is the route I have gone for my older Macs - significant boost in performance especially f you take a holistic approach (upgrade the standard HDD as well, max Ram, upgrade graphics cards, add SATA / eSata). I have a Mac Pro 1,1 06 now with SSD,  Xeon 8 core server class, 1 GB GPU, boots in 6 seconds runs 10.8 fine. Perfect for CS 6 and can crunch 8 videos at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed a (Samsung) SSD into a late 2008 Aluminum MacBook, which worked fine.

Apple does not automatically support TRIM for drives that aren't their own, but it can be enabled, for instance with this app: http://www.groths.org/trim-enabler/

Worked for me, just needs to be re-enabled after every system software update.

And yes, my MacBook is now a lot faster, so installing an SSD can definitely breathe new life into an old machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm posting this from an 24" Alu (7,1 model) which uses a Corsair SSD. I'd assume it would be the same with Samsung. Trim can be enabled.  Instructions are [here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/03/enable-trim-all-ssd-mac-os-x-lion/) (it will patch the kext driver for the SSD and worked fine for me).